# Creating a SQL Stored Procedure to aggregate data from multiple tables to create End of Month report

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Currently I am using MS Sql2000, though we are discussing upgrading this to 2005 (if that affects anything, Im guessing that it is pretty standard SQL that I need)

One of our products Tracks Sales from various departments around the country. 
Currently, I run 3 Almost identical Stored Procedures in Query Analyzer, and then copy the results into excel, and spend an hour manipulating it all onto one spreadsheet.

What I'd like to do is to come up with a solution for combining all my stored procedures so that I end up with a single, combined Dataset I can just drop into excel and mail to the interested parties.

The solution I started to come up with involved a temp table, where I would first pull in all the sites, and then in turn update this with the results from each of the queries I currently run independently, but I got into all kinds of trouble, so I figured better to start again, and to ask for guidance and help from the off.

SQL is kind of paraphrased so please dont pick me up on simple syntax errors :-)

A much simplified set of data would be;
    table site {
    id,    location}

```
table salesEnquiry {siteId, custoemrId, 
DepositDate, BalancePaidDate, Status} 
--Status can be (0,1,2,3 for not started, deposit, completed,cancelled
```

And from that, I am thinking along the lines of;

```
--Set up the Whole Table
declare @tmp TABLE (id, Site, Deposits, Completed, Cancelled) 

insert into @tmp (id, site)
select id, site from site

update @tmp
set Deposits = (select count(customerId) from salesEnquiry
    where DepositPaidDate >= @startOfMonth and DepositPaidDate <= @endOfMonth and status = 1)  

** This is the point I get lost I think, as Im not sure how to relate total number of deposits taken against the tmpId's as not all departments will take a deposit each month.
```

I would then repeat the above methodology for Completed and Cancelled Customers so I have a final table like below.

```
SiteId    Location    TotalDeposits    TotalCompleted    TotalCancelled    
  1          a             3               0                  1
  2          b             0               0                  0
  3          c             1               17                 0
```

edited to add sample data + Outcome.
** Sorry, cant figure the formatting **

Ok, hope this helps.
    site
    id   location
    1    a
    2    b
    3    c

```
salesEnquiry
id   custId   deposit      complete     status
1    1        10/05/2011   null         1
2    2        11/04/2011   11/05/2011   2
1    3        12/05/2011   null         1
1    4        13/05/2011   13/05/2011   2
3    5        14/05/2011   null         3
3    6        13/02/2011   13/05/2011   3
```

would give

```
SiteId Location Deposits Completed Cancelled
1        a       2          1        0
2        b       0          1        0
3        c       0          0        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the "and so on" indicates, but up until that point the following should work:

```
SELECT
    S.id AS SiteId,
    S.site AS Location,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SE.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalDeposits,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SE.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCompleted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SE.status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCanceled
FROM
    Sites S
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesEnquiry SE ON
    SE.customer_id = S.id AND
    (
        (
            SE.status IN (1, 3) AND
            SE.DepositPaidDate >= @startOfMonth AND
            SE.DepositPaidDate <= @endOfMonth
        ) OR
        (
            SE.status IN (2, 3) AND
            SE.BalancePaidDate >= @startOfMonth AND
            SE.BalancePaidDate <= @endOfMonth
        )
    )
GROUP BY
    S.id,
    S.site
ORDER BY
    S.id
```

I had to guess a bit on the JOIN condition. You're subquery in your question doesn't seem to be relating the Site and SalesEnquiry tables. Was it really giving you the correct numbers? Join them on whichever column is relevant. I guessed the `customer_id` and `id`.

Comment: SOrry, the and so on was just meant to indicate n more rows of results.

Comment: Gotcha. Then I think that the above will give you what you need. Let me know if you're not getting the correct results or if you need explanation on how the query works.

Comment: The problem with the answer you have there, (its my fault I should have explained more) is that completed cases need to track the completed date, so I can see those that only took a deposit in the month and those that took a completion payment seperately. Whereas a cancelled could be either deposit or completed for that month.
The sub query wasnt giving the right information, as if I try to return the id as well as the count I get an error, so I cant see how to relate a set of results to their id's short of doing a for loop

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the expected outcomes, especially with each of these cases in there somehow? It would probably make it clearer.

Comment: * Edited into original post *

Comment: Ok... I put in some logic which I think will handle what you've described above.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it tomorrow when I get in, and let you know the results!

Comment: That does exactly what I want, so thanks :-)
Appears to give subtly different answers to my old way of doing things, but I'm sure I can figure that out.